# set the div to position:relative from position:absolute; when using turn.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is a simple question, I've just started using the turn.js library and want to relatively position image elements with reference to a container div, to do this, it would look something like:

```
<div id="cont" style="position:relative;">//this div acts a page
 <img src="my.jpg" style="position: absolute; top:40px; left:50px;">
 </div>
```

the div, using the library, would serve as the page to be flipped, the problem is that whenever i set the container div to position relative, it gets turned into position absolute automatically by the turn.js library when the page loads, is there a way to ensure that the divs which get turned into pages all have position:relative; instead of position:absolute;? Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hope this may solve your problem

```
#cont {
  position:relative !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but now there's a distortion in the page transition, where i set it to position:relative !important; if i flip the page from the bottom, but i'll try to find another way.